# How can I remove dried paint from carpet and leather?

Tags: paint-removal

I placed a full tin of valspar v700 Int wall/ ceiling matt paint on the back seat of my car, the lid hadn't been put back on correctly by B & Q and it fell over all over the black leather seat and all over the carpet in the back foot weel, Does anyone know how to get this off, it happened 2 days ago,

Answer (score 1):

#### Carpet

I'd give up on the carpet and order a replacement.

#### Leather

The usual techniques for removing paint from leather are to try one of the following treatments in a small inconspicuous unpainted area of leather first to see if it harms the leather (there are a variety of ways leather is made, so results can vary), then try it on the painted leather, keep trying treatments until you find something that works.

- vegetable oil (cooking oil)
- vaseline (petroleum jelly)
- warm soapy water (and a non-scratch scouring pad used gently)
- nail polish remover
- rubbing alcohol (isopropyl alcohol)

You'll probably need to follow up with some leather conditioner.

Comment: There is a latex paint remover that I have used when our 2 year old grand son thought the paint tray was for putting his hands in and finger painting my leather chair it worked well but the carpet is probably a replace job.